# Move GitHub repository into a branch of another repository

Tags: git, github

I currently have a few GitHub repositories and would like to move those to the same repository, but on a different branch. It would be nice to maintain the histories for those repositories.

I believe it is a slight variation on the problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories) because in my case I want to move multiple repositories to the same repository but on a different Branch.

So now I have something like this:

```
- Repository X  
- Repository Y  
- Repository Z
```

And I would like this:

```
- Repository A  
   |- Branch X  
   |- Branch Y  
   |- Branch Z
```

What would be the best way to go about that whilst maintaining repository history and contributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

```
# go to your repository that you want to keep
cd RepositoryA
# fetch other repositories there
git remote add -f repositoryb [repository_b_address]
git remote add -f repositoryc [repository_c_address]
# push commits from other repositories to your main repo (repository_a)
git push origin repositoryb/master:refs/heads/branch_y
git push origin repositoryc/master:refs/heads/branch_z
```

For Git commit is a commit and it doesn't matter from which repo it came. Thus we're able to push unrelated graphs of commits into separate branches.